# Create XML element without closing tag

Tags: xml, go, xml-parsing

I have this nested golang struct:

```go
// TierRequest is the outer most XML envelope of soap request
type TierRequest struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"soapenv:Envelope"`
    NsEnv     string   `xml:"xmlns:soapenv,attr"`
    NsType    string   `xml:"xmlns:typ,attr"`
    Header    string   `xml:"soapenv:Header"`

// TierBody is an emtpy container with the GetCollectorProfile struct
type TierBody struct {
    GetCollectorProfiles GetCollectorProfile `Collectorxml:"typ:GetCollectorProfileRequest"`
}

// GetCollectorProfile struct has the context and collector number
type GetCollectorProfile struct {
    Contexts CollectorContext `xml:"typ:Context"`
    Number   int              `xml:"typ:CollectorNumber"`
}

// CollectorContext contanins a few variables as attributes
type CollectorContext struct {
    Channel  string `xml:"Channel,attr"`
    Source   string `xml:"Source,attr"`
    Language string `xml:"LanguageCode,attr"`
}
```

When I initialize it with values and marshal with `encoding/xml` it comes to look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:typ="http:/www.yahoo.com/tp/ets/2008/04/01/collector/types">
  <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <GetCollectorProfiles>
      <typ:Context Channel="WEB" Source="WEB" LanguageCode="en-CA"></typ:Context>
      <typ:CollectorNumber>50000</typ:CollectorNumber>
    </GetCollectorProfiles>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How I can get rid of the closing tags for `soapenv:Header` and `typ:Context`, so it just looks like `<soapenv:Header/>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference at the XML level between an ***element with no content and an [end-tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-ETag)***:

```
<soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
```

and an ***[empty element tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-EmptyElemTag)***:

```
<soapenv:Header/>
```

**To control which form is used, you'd have to treat the data as text rather than as XML, but better not to worry about a difference that makes no difference.**

---

[Added for completeness]

...other than an obscure and antiquated [recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#d0e2480)

> [For interoperability](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-interop), the empty-element tag should be used, and should
>   only be used, for elements which are declared EMPTY.

regarding interoperability with SGML:

> **for interoperability**
>
> [Definition: Marks a sentence describing a non-binding recommendation
>   included to increase the chances that XML documents can be processed
>   by the existing installed base of SGML processors which predate the
>   WebSGML Adaptations Annex to ISO 8879.]

Comment: Thank you @kjhughes, that's a very comprehensive answer.

Comment: Does this mean an XSD that allows 'no content' but is typed will allow an empty element tag?

Comment: @WeckarE., it means that an XSD cannot impose a constraint that differentiates between an empty element (`<e/>`) and one with no content and an end tag (`<e></e>`).

Comment: It all works fine, until you have to generate XML for some ancient ^%$&*^ hardware that used an ancient/broken XML parser to parse it's requests, and it throws an error back if empty elements aren't collapsed down to a single tag.  Sucks to be me, I guess :-(