# Is there a semantic difference between <tag /> and <tag></tag> in XML?

Tags: xml, tags, w3c

We have some kind of problem with a customer which is arguing that there is a semantical difference between two versions of empty tag in an XML file we're sending (pure XML no HTML..).

They expect:

```
 <our-xml>
    <some-tag></some-tag>
 </our-xml>
```

We send:

```
 <our-xml>
    <some-tag />
 </our-xml>
```

We are of the opinion that this is exactly the same but we could not really prove the arguments with facts. Only thing we found was in https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags where it says

> empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content.

Is there any discussion or more clear paper that we can rely on or are we wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231902/self-closing-tags-in-xml-files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### No

Start-tag/End-tag (`<tag></tag>`) and Empty-element tag (`<tag/>`) forms are semantically equivalent.  ***No conforming XML parser will treat them differently.***

---

**Reference**: 
[Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/)

- [3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags)

  - [*Tags for Empty Elements*](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#d0e2480)

    > Empty-element tags may be used for any element which has no content, whether or not it is declared using the keyword EMPTY.

---

**Historical note:** There is also an antiquated SGML compatibility reference, which I include for completeness:

> [For interoperability](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-interop), the empty-element tag should be used, and should only be used, for elements which are declared EMPTY.

- [1.2 Terminology](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-terminology)

  > **for interoperability**
  >
  > [Definition: Marks a sentence describing a non-binding recommendation included to increase the chances that XML documents can be processed by the existing installed base of SGML processors which predate the WebSGML Adaptations Annex to ISO 8879.]

---

**Related Q/A:**

- [Self-closing tags in XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7231902/290085)
- [Create XML element without closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29884177/290085)
- [Is XML's root closing tag mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42627382/290085)
- [XML with end tag and without it (self-closing tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27948432/290085)
- [What does <tag/> mean in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39184716/290085)

Comment: thank you! I'm literally astounded that you don't have "a million" upvotes for this answer ...possibly an illustration of how few people actually scrutinise the toolsets they use??

Comment: Do note that if you're writing/using a low-level parser or something what walks the XML structure, you may see a difference (a StartTag token followed by an EndTag token vs. just a Self-Closing Tag token - specifics depend on the parser you're using, and some parsers might not actually give a different parsing tree). But yeah, both are perfectly valid and need to be handled by the parser - it's a syntactic, not a semantic difference.